# Consuming CMS content via webservice on iPhone

Tags: ios, web-services, content-management-system

Am trying to find a Content Management System that I can use to produce and store content - text, images, PDFs, etc and then access this content from an iPhone using a native application via a web service.

Can anyone recommend a good CMS for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at [StorageRoom](http://storageroomapp.com), which is a flexible cloud-based CMS for Mobile Applications.

Disclaimer: I was in the same situation as you are, and didn't find anything myself, so I created this myself (I am the founder).

Answer (score 1):

SDL Tridion has the capability of exposing your published content via an oData service.

Answer (score 0):

I think that osmek is another solution. It has a range of functions and flexible pricing.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth taking a look at Cloud CMS: https://www.cloudcms.com

It's a cloud content management system for mobile and web applications, entirely oriented around JSON and having a fast, fully featured API. Your iOS application could easily grab things, render them, capture data, store it back into the CMS.

Note: I work at Cloud CMS. That said, worth checking out if for no other reason than for inspiration.